# Why doesn't command substitution work inside `find`?

Tags: bash, find, string

In bash, if try to run the function `basename` within the `-exec` option of `find`, it doesn't seem to do anything. As an example:

```
find . -name "*pdf" -exec  echo $(basename {}) \;
```

yields the filename including the directory, i.e., the same as the result of

```
find . -name "*pdf" -exec  echo {} \;
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

The `$(basename {})` snippet is parsed by your shell before `find` is executed. The result is `{}`. That's why the two commands are the same.

To make it work as you wanted you may spawn another shell that will handle `$()` on its own. Quoting with `''` prevents the outer shell from processing `$()`:

```
find -name "*pdf" -exec sh -c 'echo $(basename "$1")' sh {} \;
```

---

<sup>Note: the first version of this answer used `sh -c 'echo $(basename {})'`. This is wrong, see [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1327980/432690).</sup>